# How to cite an aside article in a bible MLA format

Tags: citations, citation-style, formatting

I have an [a NIV Arcaeological Study Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/031092605X) and am taking an Old Testament studies course.  This bible has a lot of articles about archaeology and history alongside scripture.  None of the articles have the author listed.  There is a list of contributors, but there is no way to determine which author wrote which article.

So if I wanted to cite a specific article in this bible using MLA how would I do it?  Would it be like citing an encyclopedia?

If the article is titled "The Bible and Pseudepigraphical Literature", is this correct?

> "The Bible and Pseudepigraphical Literature." *NIV Archaeological Study Bible*. 2006. Print.

Or would it be done like a collection with the editors?

> Kaiser, Walter and Duane Garrett, eds. "The Bible and Pseudepigraphical Literature." *NIV Archaeological Study Bible*. Grand Rapids: Zondervan, 2006. 2041. Print.

Or some other way?

I've been looking here for help: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/06/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your department at your university could provide some further guidance on this as they would possibly have a stylesheet developed that would deal with this type of publication.

That said, after reviewing the book at the link you provided and as per your question said it is impossible to cite the individual contributors to the book.

Because of these circumstances I believe the most appropriate way of citing this work would be as follows. Citation below is for International edition so you may need to amend based on what edition you are using.

> Kaiser, Walter C. Jr., and Duane Garrett. NIV archaeological study Bible: an illustrated walk through biblical history and culture: New International Version.. Grand Rapids, Mich.: Zondervan, 2005. Print.

This is similar to your second suggestion but drops the article title. This should be appropriate as the articles in this book appear to be half page further information pop-outs rather than full scale academic articles.

A useful site as well as the one you linked to in your question for creating citations is [Citation Machine](http://www.citationmachine.net)